# What is repl sync in the scala console?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I'm running the class scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner (better known as the scala console) under scala version 2.10.4

The -help flag outputs the following:

[image]

On the web I sporadically see another option -Yrepl-sync. Is this option still valid? What does it do? Why is it not listed with the rest of the -help content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That setting is no longer used.  It looks like 2.10.4 still uses it to init the compiler while you wait.

REPL always tries to initialize the compiler on a separate thread so you don't twiddle your thumbs.

Here is the copious "illusion of snappiness" comment:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/ILoop.scala#L867

Answer (score 2):

```
scala -Y
```

prints a number of other options which include:

> *-Yrepl-sync*  do not use asynchronous code for repl startup